# Insertar en campo enum (mysql) multiples values de checkbox

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox, insert, update

necesito ayuda para insertar multiples values en mysql de un checkbox en un formulario:

- Tengo estos checkbox en mi formulario

```html
<LABEL>Extras (los que procedan):</LABEL>
<INPUT TYPE="checkbox" NAME="extras[]" VALUE="Vista Al Mar">Vista al Mar
<INPUT TYPE="checkbox" NAME="extras[]" VALUE="Piscina">Piscina
<INPUT TYPE="checkbox" NAME="extras[]" VALUE="Jardin">Jardin
<input type="checkbox" NAME="extras[]" VALUE="Quincho">Quincho
<INPUT TYPE="checkbox" NAME="extras[]" VALUE="Estacionamiento">Estacionamiento
```

- En mi tabla MySql del formulario tengo esa columna como

extras = ENUM('Vista al Mar','Piscina','Jardin','Quincho','Estacionamiento')

- Este es mi codigo php en donde inserto el formulario:

```html
<?php

include("../conexion.php");  


 insertarVivienda($_POST['tipo'], $_POST['zona'], $_POST['direccion'], $_POST['ndorm'],$_POST['precio'],$_POST['tamano'],$_POST['extras[]'],$_POST['foto'],
                     $_POST['observaciones'],$_POST['tipo_servicio']);

function insertarVivienda($tipo,$zona,$direccion,$ndormitorios,$precio,$tamano,$extras,$foto,$observaciones,$tipo_servicio)
{
echo $query = "INSERT INTO `vivienda` (`idvivienda`, `tipo_vivienda`, `zona`, `direccion`, `ndormitorios`, `precio`, `tamano`, `extras`, `foto`, `observaciones`, `usuario_id`,tipo_servicio) VALUES ('Null', '".$tipo."', '".$zona."', '".$direccion."', '".$ndormitorios."', '".$precio."', '".$tamano."', '".$extras."', '".$foto."', '".$observaciones."','".$tipo_servicio.", '1')";
 $conexion = conectar();
 mysqli_query($conexion,$query) or die (mysqli_error());     
}

?>
```

- Todos los otros datos se insertan sin problemas,aún no valido nada y
  permito vacios solo para ver que sucede,pero cuando seleciono 1 o mas
  check box me tira este error:

```html
Notice: Undefined index: extras[] in C:\xampp\htdocs\inmobiliaria\crud\insertar.php on line 6
INSERT INTO `vivienda` (`idvivienda`, `tipo_vivienda`, `zona`, `direccion`, `ndormitorios`, `precio`, `tamano`, `extras`, `foto`, `observaciones`, `usuario_id`) VALUES ('Null', 'Departamento', 'El Tabo', '', '1', '', '', '', '', '', '1')
```

con lo demas esta todo ok,antes no tenia problemas cuando usaba "extras" como combo box pero necesito selecionar más de 1 extra por lo que pense usar checkbox...

muchas gracias.

Comment: Lo primero es que no puedes almacenar multiples valores en un campo enum, solo puedes establecer uno de los predefinidos en cada registro. Por otro lado `$_POST['extras[]']` esto no es correcto, es `$_POST['extras']` y contendra un array de los valores seleccionados. pero en la consulta no puedes pasar un array, la consulta sql debe ser una cadena (string), por lo que si lo pasas directamente no funcionara.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que tienes que hacer es

1. Modificar tu tabla `viviendas` y sacar el campo `extras` de esta.
2. Crear una tabla, de nombre `extras`, con los campos `id` (`autonumerico`), y `nombre` (`varchar` de 50), aqui pones todos los extras que pueda tener una vivienda.
3. Crear una tabla relacional (N:M)(muchos a muchos), que tendra 3 campos: `id` (`autonumerico`), `idVivienda` que seran los `id` de `vivienda` y `idExtra` que seran los `id` de `extras`.

Esta tabla relacionara todos los extras que tenga una vivienda.

Haciendo un simple `SELECT` sabrás que extras tiene una vivienda.

Otra solución mas chapucera es que lo guardes todo en una ristra de texto separado, por ejemplo por `|`  (pipe).

Si lo hicieras así, para recuperalo tiene que hacer un `split` del `SELECT. Pero, como te digo es una chapuza.

Espero te ayude, suerte.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que tiene que hace es lo siguiente, como el dato es un array, lo que tiene que hace es utilizar un foreach.
El tipo enum solo puede guarda un solo tipo de dato especifico, definido en la base de dato.
el tipo de datos que quiere guarda que tiene varios tipos de datos, tiene una relación de mucho a mucho y eso se ver en base de datos, por lo cual tiene que crear una tabla donde tiene que guardad : vivienda_id y extras_id

```
<?php

include("../conexion.php");  


 insertarVivienda($_POST['tipo'], $_POST['zona'], $_POST['direccion'], $_POST['ndorm'],$_POST['precio'],$_POST['tamano'],$_POST['extras'],$_POST['foto'],
                     $_POST['observaciones'],$_POST['tipo_servicio']);

function insertarVivienda($tipo,$zona,$direccion,$ndormitorios,$precio,$tamano,$extras,$foto,$observaciones,$tipo_servicio)
{

echo $query = "INSERT INTO `vivienda` (`idvivienda`, `tipo_vivienda`, `zona`, `direccion`, `ndormitorios`, `precio`, `tamano`,`foto`, `observaciones`, `usuario_id`,tipo_servicio) VALUES ('Null', '".$tipo."', '".$zona."', '".$direccion."', '".$ndormitorios."', '".$precio."', '".$tamano."','".$foto."', '".$observaciones."','".$tipo_servicio.", '1')";
 $conexion = conectar();
    //mysqli_query($conexion,$query) or die (mysqli_error());     
    //devuelve el id de la fila insertada 
    if(mysqli_query($conn, $query)) {
        $vivienda_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
        $vivienda_id;
        foreach ($extras as $extras_id) {
        $query = "INSERT INTO `vivienda_extras` (`vivienda_id`, `extras_id`) VALUES ('".$vivienda_id."', '".$extras_id."')";
            mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

        }

    }



}

?>
```

Comment: En realidad, lo que tiene que hacer es una tabla n:m que relaciones tantos extras como sea necesario para tantas viviendas como sean necesarias.